# flask get method which accepts a parameter : Missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, flask

I have the following flask code

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request                                                                                                                                                                          
from webargs import fields                                                                                                                                                                                         
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, select                                                                                                                                                      
from flask_cors import CORS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
engine = create_engine('...')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
////                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
app = Flask(__name__)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/list*": {"origins": "*"}})                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

@app.route('/list-vessels', methods=['GET'])                                                                                                                                                                       
def list_vessels():                                                                                                                                                                                                    
vessel_list = []                                                                                                                                                                                                   
s = select([vesseldetail.c.Vessel])                                                                                                                                                                                
rp = connection.execute(s)                                                                                                                                                                                         
for row in rp:                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    vessel_list.extend(list(row))                                                                                                                                                                                  
return jsonify(vessel_list)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

@app.route('/list-keydates', methods=['GET'])                                                                                                          
def list_keydates(vesselname):                                                                                                                                                                                         
    vesselname = request.args['vesselname']      
    intervention_list = []                                                                                                                                                                                             
    keydate_list = []                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    s = select([keydate.c.Intervention, keydate.c.Date])                                                                                                                                                               
    s = s.where(keydate.c.VESSEL==vesselname)                                                                                                                                                                          
    rp = connection.execute(s)                                                                                                                                                                                         
    for row in rp:                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        intervention_list.append((row[0]))                                                                                                                                                                                 
        keydate_list.append((row[1]))                                                                                                                                                                                  
    return jsonify({"keydates": keydate_list, "intervention": intervention_list})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The second endpoint 'list-keydates' returns a `TypeError: list_keydates() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vesselname'` even when I pass a vesselname in the query string. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument `vesselname` is missing when defining the url, try the following:

```
...
@app.route('/list-keydates/<vesselname>', methods=['GET'])                                                                                                          
def list_keydates(vesselname):
    intervention_list = []                                                                                                                                                                                             
    keydate_list = []                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    s = select([keydate.c.Intervention, keydate.c.Date])                                                                                                                                                               
    s = s.where(keydate.c.VESSEL==vesselname)  
    ...
```

url should be `http://.../list-keydates/name-of-the-vessel`

This way you don't have to get the vesselname from request args, its value will be placed in the variable function.

Hope it suits you well

Comment: Hi. This works, thanks! But I would still like to know why the other thing doesn't. How would I need to edit the code so I could use request args?

Comment: No problem! To use request args, you could remove the argument from your function - e.g:  `def list_keydates():` - then call the url in the following way: `http://.../list-keydates?vesselname=name-of-the-vessel`.

Answer (score 3):

you can also do this

when there is a query string in the URL

**http://localhost:5000/list-keydates?vesselname=yourdata**

```
@app.route('/list-keydates', methods=['GET'])                                                                                                          
def list_keydates():
    print(request.args['vesselname']                                                                                                                                                                        
    vesselname = request.args['vesselname']
```